# How to fetch image and display it on next page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, webforms

I am implementing a form to get personal details of user and an image of user for DP. How do i display it on next page if data is submitted correctly.

Comment: You store it when the form is submitted, and retrieve it when you want to show it. For a more specific response, please ask a more specific question (code?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you,

The upload form.

```
  <html>
  <head><title>File Upload To Database</title></head>
  <body>
  <h2>Please Choose a File and click Submit</h2>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="99999999" />
  <div><input name="userfile" type="file" /></div>
  <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
  </form>

</body></html>
```

Uploading the image.

```
<?php
/*** check if a file was submitted ***/
if(!isset($_FILES['userfile']))
    {
    echo '<p>Please select a file</p>';
    }
else
    {
    try    {
        upload();
        /*** give praise and thanks to the php gods ***/
        echo '<p>Thank you for submitting</p>';
        }
    catch(Exception $e)
        {
        echo '<h4>'.$e->getMessage().'</h4>';
        }
    }
?>
```

The upload function

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * the upload function
 * 
 * @access public
 *
 * @return void
 *
 */
function upload(){
/*** check if a file was uploaded ***/
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) && getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) != false)
    {
    /***  get the image info. ***/
    $size = getimagesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
    /*** assign our variables ***/
    $type = $size['mime'];
    $imgfp = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
    $size = $size[3];
    $name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $maxsize = 99999999;


    /***  check the file is less than the maximum file size ***/
    if($_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize )
        {
        /*** connect to db ***/
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testblob", 'username', 'password');

                /*** set the error mode ***/
                $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            /*** our sql query ***/
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO testblob (image_type ,image, image_size, image_name) VALUES (? ,?, ?, ?)");

        /*** bind the params ***/
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $type);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $imgfp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $size);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $name);

        /*** execute the query ***/
        $stmt->execute();
        }
    else
        {
        /*** throw an exception is image is not of type ***/
        throw new Exception("File Size Error");
        }
    }
else
    {
    // if the file is not less than the maximum allowed, print an error
    throw new Exception("Unsupported Image Format!");
    }
}
?>
```

Displaying the image

```
<?php

/*** some basic sanity checks ***/
if(filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, "image_id") !== false && filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'image_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false)
    {
    /*** assign the image id ***/
    $image_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "image_id", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    try     {
        /*** connect to the database ***/
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testblob", 'username', 'password');

        /*** set the PDO error mode to exception ***/
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        /*** The sql statement ***/
        $sql = "SELECT image, image_type FROM testblob WHERE image_id=$image_id";

        /*** prepare the sql ***/
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

        /*** exceute the query ***/
        $stmt->execute(); 

        /*** set the fetch mode to associative array ***/
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        /*** set the header for the image ***/
        $array = $stmt->fetch();

        /*** check we have a single image and type ***/
        if(sizeof($array) == 2)
            {
            /*** set the headers and display the image ***/
            header("Content-type: ".$array['image_type']);

            /*** output the image ***/
            echo $array['image'];
            }
        else
            {
            throw new Exception("Out of bounds Error");
            }
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    catch(Exception $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        }
  else
        {
        echo 'Please use a real id number';
        }
?>
```

If you want any other information, you canrefer to this link:

```
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Storing-Images-in-MySQL-with-PHP.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing values between pages, there are many ways.

1. Store in session and use on next page. Delete that session later if not in use
2. If you are fetching details using Ajax form post, then things are more simple. Get details and store in session or any hidden parameter of form. Post to next page.